# Can you eat foods during Passover, if you already opened and ate from the package before Passover?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, food, passover, chametz-leaven

Let's say that a person opens a jar of pickles that is kosher for Passover, and eats from it during the week before Passover starts.

Can the jar still be used during Passover?

Comment: Isn't this how everyone cooks food for the seder on the first night of passover? By opening stuff and cooking it before passover starts?

Comment: That would depend on how the jar is kept to avoid getting chametz in it.

Comment: @DoubleAA you are correct of course but I presume the OP means open and sitting in fridge during general circulation, not open after everything has been kashered/ moved. OP: I know it was an example, but to consider with pickles, maybe a year-round (used for chometz) fork used to get some out is a problem if the vinegar is davar charif.